# Filter news feeds via sgrep

Tags: xml, filter, grep, rss, atom-feed

Using Liferea feed reader it's possible to specify a script that filters incoming feed data using stdin/stdout, e. g. via a shell script. For instance

```
sgrep  '("<entry>" .. "</entry>") containing "foo"'
```

only outputs entries containing *foo*, but also strips `<?xml .. ><feed .. >` and `</feed>`.

Has someone already a sgrep filter ready for (atom) feeds?

Comment: Have you considered `xsltproc` instead?

Comment: Could be a more current/practical approach, thanks!